# When edit name, display the same name item on a dropdown menu in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drop-down-menu

I have a simple AngularJS form that is connected to the database.

The form displays list of names and country of birth on an HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="max-width: 100%;" id="myAreas">
    <tr ng-repeat="name in Names">
        <td>{{name.FullName}}</td>
        <td>                               
            <select ng-model="selectedCountryForEdit" ng-show="editMode">
                <option ng-repeat="z in countryList" value="{{z.CountryCode}}">{{z.CountryName}}</option>
            </select>
            <span style="display: block;" ng-show="!editMode">{{areaItem.Countries}}</span>
        </td>                            
        <td><a href="" ng-click="editMode = !editMode"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>                    
</table>
```

The table use the following JS/Angular code:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetNames')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.Names = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

And the JS/Angular is calling a method on MVC to list data from the database.

I don't want to include the MVC code because it is working fine and my issue relies on something else:

If look at the html table, there is a pencil icon with each row that allows me to display a dropdown menu instead of the country.

What I am doing is filling the drop-down menu with list of countries from the database and I want the dropdown menu display the same country of the selected row/name.

I searched a lot and I could not find how to solve this issue. I am very new to Angular and JS and I hope you can advise on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `ng-model` of the select to the attribute in the `Names` array.
ex. if Names has att country so the `ng-model` instead `selectedCountryForEdit`, will be the same of the `Names`.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="max-width: 100%;" id="myAreas">
    <tr ng-repeat="name in Names">
        <td>{{name.FullName}}</td>
        <td>                               
            <select ng-model="name.country" ng-show="editMode">
                <option ng-repeat="z in countryList" value="{{z.CountryCode}}">{{z.CountryName}}</option>
            </select>
            <span style="display: block;" ng-show="!editMode">{{areaItem.Countries}}</span>
        </td>                            
        <td><a href="" ng-click="editMode = !editMode"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
    </tr>                    
</table>
```

also will recoment to change te select options ng-repeat to ng-options cause this one has better performance.

example:

```
<select ng-model="name.country" ng-show="editMode" ng-options="z.countryCode as z.CountryName for z in countryList">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out and I will get back to you